# Arduino, Breaking Stepper motor in the for loop

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

Need to break the Stepper motor operation within "for loop". But the code that I have written breaks the operation after the completion of the loop, it does not break the operation between the loop. Please chek the code and tell me any possible way to stop the loop in between..

Code:

```cpp
#include <Stepper.h>
int in1Pin = 8;
int in2Pin = 9;
int in3Pin = 10;
int in4Pin = 12;

bool entry = false;
int j;

Stepper motor(200, in1Pin, in2Pin, in3Pin, in4Pin);

void setup() {
  pinMode(in1Pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2Pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3Pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4Pin, OUTPUT);

  while (!Serial);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  motor.setSpeed(300);
  Serial.println("Type in your selection");
  entry = false;
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0){
    switch(Serial.read()){
      case 'a':
       entry = true;
       break;
      case 'b':
       entry = false;
       break;
      default:break;
    }
  }
  if(entry == true){
        for(j = -20; j <= 20; j++){
          motor.step(j/0.176);
        }
      }
  else if(entry == false){
       digitalWrite(in1Pin,LOW);
       digitalWrite(in2Pin,LOW);
       digitalWrite(in3Pin,LOW);
       digitalWrite(in4Pin,LOW);
  }

}
```

*From Comments:* when i send 'a' through serial monitor, the stepper starts rotating, when i send 'b' through serial it should break stepper motor rotation, but its breaking only after the completion of loop (not within the loop)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking

Comment: when i send 'a' through serial monitor, the stepper starts rotating, when i send 'b' through serial it should break stepper motor rotation, but its breaking only after the completion of loop (not within the loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't give a chance to *Arduino* to parse the *serial input* in-between the execution of the `for` loop, then obviously is not going to work as you want.

You should do something similar to this:

```cpp
...

void loop() {
  static int j;

  if (Serial.available() > 0){
    switch(Serial.read()){
      case 'a':
       entry = true;

       /**
        * replace next 3 lines with `j = -20` if you want to start
        * the loop from scratch each time `a` is received,
        * instead of resuming from where you stopped.
        */
       if (j >= 20) {
         j = -20;
       }

       break;
      case 'b':
       entry = false;
       break;
      default:break;
    }
  }

  if (entry) {
    if (j <= 20) {
      motor.step(j/0.176);
      ++j;
    }
  } else {
     digitalWrite(in1Pin, LOW);
     digitalWrite(in2Pin, LOW);
     digitalWrite(in3Pin, LOW);
     digitalWrite(in4Pin, LOW);
  }
}
```

In this code, I let *Arduino* parse a new character after each call to `motor.step()`. Note that this approach introduces a *tiny* delay among sub-sequent calls to `motor.step()` wrt. your original solution, but it should be *negligible* in practice.

If you send multiple `a` in a row to *Arduino* using this code, but *Arduino* did not complete the `for` loop yet, then with this code the additional `a` will be ignored. If you want to handle them as additional `for` request, then you should add a `counter` to keep track of the number of pending (full) iterations of the `for` loop that you want to perform.

Comment: Its working but a small change is that I removed the "if loop" from the switch statement and added to the external "if loop"...Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @VinayMJois If you do that, then it will continue rotating endlessly. If that's what you want, I'll update my answer to reflect it.